# How to get data join four tables with Spring mvc and MyBatis

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I'm using Spring and MyBatis, I'm facing with the problem when join four tables to get data in JSP
my model:

User:

```
public class User {     
   private Long user_id;
   private GroupMaster group_id; 
   private String login_name;
   private String password;
   private String full_name;
   private String full_name_kana;
   private String email;
   private String tel;
   private Date birthday;
   private boolean rule;
   private String salt;
   // getter and setter
}
```

DetailUser:

```
public class DetailUserVN {
   private Long detail_user_vn_id;
   private User user_id;
   private String code_level;
   private Date start_date;
   private Date end_start;
   private int total;
   // getter and setter
}
```

GroupMaster:

```
public class GroupMaster {  
   private Long group_id;
   private String group_name;
   // getter and setter
}
```

VNMaster:

```
class VNMaster {
   private String code_level;   
   private String name_level;
   // getter and setter
}
```

UserMapper.java

```
@Select("SELECT users.user_id, "
        + "users.full_name, "
        + "users.birthday, "
        + "mst_group.group_name, "
        + "users.email, users.tel, "
        + "mst_vn.name_level, "
        + "tbl_detail_user_vn.end_date, "
        + "tbl_detail_user_vn.total "           
+ "FROM users "
+ "INNER JOIN tbl_detail_user_vn " 
+   "ON tbl_detail_user_vn.detail_user_vn_id = users.user_id "    
+ "INNER JOIN mst_vn " 
+   "ON mst_vn.code_level = tbl_detail_user_vn.code_level "   
+ "INNER JOIN mst_group "
+   "ON mst_group.group_id = users.group_id")   
public List<User> getAllUsers();
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
public List<User> getAllUsers() {
    return userMapper.getAllUsers();        
}
```

UserController:

```
public class UserController {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;
@RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String getAllUser(ModelMap model) {
List<User> listUser = userService.getAllUsers();
        model.put("listUser", listUser);
        logger.info("list of renter is: " + listUser);

        return "getUser";
  }
}
```

getUser.jsp:

```
<div class="">                              
        <c:if test="${not empty listUser}">
            <table border="1" cellpadding="5">
                <tr>
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">ID</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">Họ tên ▲▽</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">Ngày sinh</th>                               
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">Phòng ban</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">Email</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">Phone number</th>                        
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">Tring do ▲▽</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">Ngay het han ▲▽</th>
                    <th style="background-color: #e9ecef;">Tong</th>
                </tr>
                <c:forEach items="${listUser}" var="user">
                <tr>
                    <td>${user.user_id}</td>
                    <td>${user.full_name}</td>
                    <td>${user.birthday}</td>     
                    <td>${user.group_id.group_name}</td>                        
                    <td>${user.email}</td>
                    <td>${user.tel}</td>
                    <td>${mst_vn.name_level}</td>
                    <td>${tbl_detail_user_vn.end_date}</td>
                    <td>${tbl_detail_user_vn.total}</td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </table>
        </c:if>                                 
    </div>
```

When I build it seem is not happen error but some value can not get from database

example:

```
<td>${user.group_id.group_name}</td>
<td>${mst_vn.name_level}</td>
<td>${tbl_detail_user_vn.end_date}</td>
<td>${tbl_detail_user_vn.total}</td>
```

How to fix this error and get data for this?

**Updated:**

```
org.apache.ibatis.reflection.ReflectionException: There is no setter for property named 'user' in 'class com.you.springmybatis.model.User'
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL query returns the result set with data that is required but you have not specified how to map this result set to the object structure you use.

Let's consider one field value you try to display `user.group_id.group_name` (for other fields the situation is more complex, see below some thoughts about this).

The data for group name is returned in the field that has name `group_name` in the result set. But mybatis does not know that for this field and object of type `GroupMaster` should be created and that the value from `group_name` should be set to the `group_name` property of that object.

You need to specify the mapping for the *association* between `User` and `GroupMaster` entities. Unfortunately when you select the entity and associated entity via single query using a join it is not possible to map such association using annotations in mybatis. But this can be done using xml mapping.

But before you start you need to include unique id of every entity that participates in the join to the result set. That means you need to include `group_id` etc. Without these fields mybatis will create duplicate entities but you most probably want to have only one `GroupMaster` created for different `User` entities if they refer to the same record in `mst_group` table.

You create xml mapping in `UserMapper.xml` that resides in the same package as `UserMapper` interface similar to this:

```
<resultMap id="userMap" type="User">
  <id property="user_id" column="user_id"/>
  <result property="full_name" column="full_name"/>
  <result property="birthday" column="birthday"/>
  <association property="group_id" javaType="GroupMaster">
    <id property="group_id" column="group_id"/>
    <result property="group_name" column="group_name"/>
  </association>
</resultMap>
```

Then you can reference this resultmap in the mapper:

```
@ResultMap("com.you.mapper.UserMapper.userMap")
@Select("SELECT users.user_id, "
        + "users.full_name, "
        + "users.birthday, "
        + "mst_group.group_name, "
        + "users.email, users.tel, "
        + "mst_vn.name_level, "
        + "tbl_detail_user_vn.end_date, "
        + "tbl_detail_user_vn.total "           
+ "FROM users "
+ "INNER JOIN tbl_detail_user_vn " 
+   "ON tbl_detail_user_vn.detail_user_vn_id = users.user_id "    
+ "INNER JOIN mst_vn " 
+   "ON mst_vn.code_level = tbl_detail_user_vn.code_level "   
+ "INNER JOIN mst_group "
+   "ON mst_group.group_id = users.group_id")   
public List<User> getAllUsers();
```

Let's see in details how association mapping works:

```
<resultMap id="RM" type="A">
  <association property="pB" javaType="B">
    <id property="id" column="b_id"/>
    <result property="name" column="b_name"/>
  </association>
</resultMap>
```

This specifies that for every result row (that represents object of type `A`) an object of type `B` should be created and its properties `id` and `name` should be set from columns `b_id` and `b_name` respectively.

So the above mapping for you example specifies that fields `group_id` and `group_name` should be put into the properties of the object of type `GroupMaster` and that object should be assigned to the `group_id` property of the `User` entity.

Several notes:

1. your data structure is a bit incorrect namely `group_id` field in `User` actually stores not the id of the group, but the actual object so it should be renamed to `group`.
2. usual naming convention for properties is a camel-case identifiers, that is instead of `full_name` the property should be `fullName` etc.

There is a problem with mapping of joins to `mst_vn` and `tbl_detail_user_vn` as there are no field representing this associations in the `User`. You need to think about how you want you object tree should look like to represent the data you want to fetch from the database.

For `tbl_detail_user_vn` you probably need to add a field to `User`:

```
private DetailUserVN detail;
```

Then you will be able to map this association using the same method as for `GroupMaster`.

Comment: Hi @Roman Konoval, I have updated with your solution, but it happen an error as I have updated in my question

Comment: You shouldn't use the code blindly. It was not tested and is here only to demonstrate the idea. I've fixed the typo in the map definition that causes the issue but there may be others.

Comment: I have updated and modify base on your idea, It is good, So in UserMapper.xml I can use: <association property="code_level" javaType="VNMaster"> for another table ?

Comment: No, you can't do that because there is no `code_level` property in `User`. I've added explanation what association mapping means and how it works.